# CPU% more than 100 in ps -aux

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, ps

We use ps -aux to find out when tomcat process takes high CPU utilization, if that so we will send a alert to Group. But some times %CPU shows more than 100, but our application working fine. Is it bad sign or whether our understanding is correct fins CPU usage for a process

This is the output When I execute the command,

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     16228 106 24.0 2399428 1840576 ?     Sl   07:11 171:35 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat-rc-core-v1-inst01/conf/logging.properties -Dj
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Edited my Question, Here it shows CPU% 106 for tomcat process, But the application is working without any issues, Some other process is also running in the system and working without any issues. Is it bad sign when it shows more than 100 or is it normal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How many cores do you have on this server? 106% means it's occupying a full core plus a little of another. So, if you have say, 4 cores, a process that is multi-threaded (so it can handle pushing load to all cores) could reach 400%. `top` will confirm this behavior.

Comment: That's right. =)

Comment: When I first saw a process was using `360` I was worried my PC was about to blow up! Good to know I'm safe.